# Why are these two pieces of code returning different values?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scope

I'm learning Javascript through the online book "Eloquent JavaScript" - Which is an awesome resource by the way. I came across this function in the Data Structures chapter:

```
function tableFor(event,journal){
var table = [0,0,0,0]; 
for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++){
    var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
    if (hasEvent(event,entry)) index += 1; 
    if (entry.squirrel) index += 2; 
        table[index] += 1;
    }
return table;
}
```

As you can see it iterates across an array, and outputs another array depending on how many times the first object had the argument:event. I rewrote this slightly different like this...

```
function tableFor(event,journal){
var table = [0,0,0,0];
for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++){ 
    var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
    if (hasEvent(event,entry)){
        index += 1;
        }
    if (entry.squirrel){
        index += 2; 
        table[index] += 1;
        }
}
return table;
}
```

The only change is the brackets around the if statements, which I thought was best practice. However, it outputs a different value from the first piece of code. Why is this happening? Is there some scope problem that I don't understand?? If you don't know what I'm talking about, here is a link to the chapter in the book: [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html)
and a link to the object JOURNAL:[JavaScript Object](http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/jacques_journal.js)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you put brackets wrong, `table[index] += 1;` should be outside if

Comment: Because your indentation is very misleading. Fix it.

Comment: What about my indentation is misleading?

Comment: the items are usually indented under the function they're a part of. The indentation of `table{index\ +=1` implies that it's related to the if statement above it, when it's not. It should be one tab over to the left, flush with the statements above it.

Answer (score 2):

In the original code, this:

```
if (entry.squirrel) index += 2; 
    table[index] += 1;
```

is actually two unrelated statements:

```
if (entry.squirrel) { index += 2; }
table[index] += 1;
```

It's just badly indented.  In Javascript, as in most C-derived languages, a single statement after an `if` can constitute the block to be executed when the condition is true.  To include more than one statement, braces must be used.

Answer (score 2):

An *if* statement without brackets will only execute the next instruction when the conditions are met.

The first snippet you provided contains confusing indentation as it suggests the following instruction ("table[index] += 1;") is part of the conditional statement, but in JavaScript indentation is insignificant.

So in reality, if you're using not using brackets, the first semicolon expression is where closing bracket would be.

Correctly indented code:

```
function tableFor(event,journal){
    var table = [0,0,0,0]; 
    for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++){
        var entry = journal[i], index = 0;

        if (hasEvent(event,entry)) index += 1; 
        if (entry.squirrel) index += 2; 

        table[index] += 1;
   }

   return table;
}
```

With brackets

```
function tableFor(event,journal){
    var table = [0,0,0,0]; 
    for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++){
        var entry = journal[i], index = 0;

        if (hasEvent(event,entry)) {
            index += 1
        }; 

        if (entry.squirrel) {
            index += 2
        }; 

        table[index] += 1;
   }

   return table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've put 'table[index] += 1;' inside an if statement, where it wasn't before.  The tabbing in the original code gives a misleading impression but the original unbracketed if statement only 'wrapped' around  'index += 2;'

Answer (score 1):

It's because you placed the brackets in the wrong place. It should read like so:

```
function tableFor(event,journal){
var table = [0,0,0,0];
for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++){ 
var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
if (hasEvent(event,entry)){
    index += 1;
    }
if (entry.squirrel){
    index += 2; 
    }
    table[index] += 1;
}
return table;
```

The table[index] line doesn't belong in the if statement.

Comment: No, it should not read like that. It should be properly indented.

Comment: I meant as far as brackets are concerned.